# Overflow on a table cell

Tags: html, css

I have a regular table with TD's widths in %. I want that, when the text written in a cell is longer that the cell width, the text overflows the cell and that overflown is visible. Right now if the text is longer, it breaks ups to the next line. I tried word-break: keep-all !important; but it doesn't seems to work. What should I try?

Comment: can you add your markup and html

Comment: Did you try `white-space: nowrap;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For responsive layouts, use the max-width CSS property to specify the effective minimum width of the column, or just use max-width: 0; for unlimited flexibility. Also, the containing table will need a specific width, typically width: 100%;, and the columns will typically have their width set as percentage of the total width. You can try like this.

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    max-width: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td.columnA {
    width: 30%;
}
td.columnB {
    width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: Something like that but without text-overflow: ellipsis and with overflow:visible! Edit that and I can chose it as right answer!

Comment: Glad it worked. I have edited as you suggested. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add `white-space: nowrap ;`to the table cell

this will make the text in one line and will not break

Comment: This doesn't work for me, at least in Chrome. It has no affect.